# Is asking about a problem encountered while using Watson Studio within the scope of the site?

Tags: discussion, scope

While following an IBM course about artificial intelligence, I encountered a problem when using their [Watson Studio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Watson_Studio) service in IBM Cloud (specifically when trying to create an [AutoAI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AutoAI) experiment).

I tried searching about the problem in other places on the web, but I didn't find anything related. So, I was wondering whether asking for a solution of such a problem be within the scope of the site. And, if so, what would be some of the appropriate tags?

Comment: Does the problem you have include writing code?

Comment: @BDL No it doesn't.

Comment: You should probably ask IBM support.

Comment: @RobertLongson I don't have access to that.

Comment: [Really, what about this?](https://community.ibm.com/community/user/ai-datascience/communities/community-home3)

Comment: @MehdiCharife: If it doesn't include programming, then it's certainly off-topic on SO.

Comment: @RobertLongson That's not IBM support though https://www.ibm.com/mysupport/s/

Comment: @BDL Really? I remember reading something about questions regarding tools used by programmers can be on topic.

Comment: The point is that there are various avenues of support offered by IBM. And it's tools used by programmers to do programming, your first comment suggests that this isn't one of those cases.

Comment: @MehdiCharife: The help center states: "- software tools commonly used by programmers; - and is a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development" That covers all types of programs that you need to do software development (like IDEs). If your problem doesn't involve programming, then I wouldn't consider the tool a tool primarily used by software developers.

Comment: What *is* Watson Studio? What do you do in it? The [site](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cloud-paks/cp-data/3.5.0?topic=services-watson-studio) states *"You can choose the tools you need to analyze and visualize data, to cleanse and shape data, to ingest streaming data, or to create and train machine learning models."* Which doesn't *sound* like an IDE or tool a programmer would use, such as VSCode or DBeaver.

Comment: @ThomA You can use jupyter notebook inside Watson Studio though, which is an IDE. https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cloud-paks/cp-data/4.6.x?topic=notebooks-coding-running

Comment: I could write code in MS Word, @MehdiCharife , that doesn't make it (MS Word) on topic.

Comment: @ThomA But MS Word is not an IDE. Jupyter notebook is though.

Comment: @ThomA Just so that you know, there is actually a tag called `watson-studio` in StackOverflow. From the tag info: 

*"IBM Watson Studio, a product that helps accelerate the machine and deep learning workflows required to infuse AI into your business to drive innovation. It provides a suite of tools for data scientists, application developers and subject matter experts to collaboratively and easily work with data and use that data to build, train and deploy models at scale.*"

https://stackoverflow.com/tags/watson-studio/info

Comment: That still doesn't sound on-topic; the existence of a tag doesn't make a specific subject (on it's own) on-topic. And if you are asking about Jupyter Notebooks, then tag that. Like with the prior example, I wouldn't tag [[tag:ms-word]] because I'm, for some silly reason, writing code in Word; I'd tag the language I'm writing.

Comment: @ThomA I didn't claim that it was on topic. This is the point of this post. I just pointed to the false equivalence you were making between MS-Word and Jupyter Notebook and your claim regarding  Watson Studio not sounding like a tool a programmer would use, which is clearly false according to the tag info and IBM's own site. I was not implying that the question mentioned in this post is on-topic. I was merely explaining how the reasons that you gave for the question being off-topic were wrong.

Comment: I wasn't making any comparison to Jupyter Notebooks, your question is about Watson Studio, not Jupyter Notebooks.

Comment: As it appears that Watson Studio is more of a data-science tool than an IDE. Perhaps [datascience.stackexchange](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/) would be more appropriate?